# Can a Controller have database queries (MySQL)? If yes, when?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, model-view-controller, frameworks

I am reading lots of tutorials on MVC, so my question, can a perfect PHP MVC framework have database queries in Controller? As I understand, the most comfortable way is to put all database queries in Model, right? And if I have POST or smth, I just pass that POST to Model and it makes all inserts and etc. ?

Or I am missing something? And if Controller can have a database queries, in which situation would it be?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No controller may not have any db related code - any DB queries may be stored in model in MVC architecture - controller only works with models, but not directly with DB

EDIT: Most frameworks will allow calling SQL directly from Controller - but then it is not MVC, but bunch of objects

Comment: And what about the views? Should my view have it? u___u x_x I didn't find any question about it.

Comment: No, it shouldn't, any data required for View must be prepared in controller. Only alternative I'm using is helper functions, but this is not clean MVC then.

Answer (score 7):

No Controller must not IDEALLY and CONCEPTUALLY contain any database queries. If you have some queries in the controller itself then it will take away some key advantages of the MVC architecture such as Code Segregation and so on.

Ideally your,
Model Classes (M) must contain DB queries and any interactions with DB via DB objects. A model ideally represents a Table in the DB or a file used for io

Views (V) must contain HTML with very little PHP. In most conditions only loops and conditional statements are used

Controller Classes (C) must contain all the business logic of you application, error handlers and so on.

It is very useful to maintain the MVC Architecture in regards to Maintain, Debug and also code understanding form a new developers prospective. The norms bring in a lot of benefits as mentioned above.

Comment: I agree to disagree.  Controllers should be used for nothing more than controlling the flow of an application.  Error handling and business logic should be included into your models.  I like to know models can 100% stand on their own.  They handle their own validation, logic, and error handling.  I guess we all have differing opinions.

Answer (score 4):

Technically - yes, it is possible. But it would break the whole idea behind MVC.

Comment: So, why CodeIgniter allows that?

Comment: @OZ_ : Lol, that was honest :D

Comment: Well, some might see it as lame, but I believe it's just to allow some applications to be simpler, when needed. That's one of the great advantages of CodeIgniter over other frameworks - it's up to you how to build your app, and if you have just 2 SQL queries in it - why write a model? Again - that breaks the MVC model, but it can be useful.

Comment: if you make simplier application now , and you will save quater of time on this, when you will modify this application in future, this nonMVC-s will cost you much more time than you saved on it

Comment: True, but I'm not talking about applications dealing with large ammounts of data, but rather one where you only need to execute 2 or 3 queries - why would I write a model that only contains one method? If you need to expand it - you can always copy-paste the query in a newly created model and replace it.

Comment: if you "copy-paste" your code - something is wrong ( in case you wrote, wrong is original design without model )

Answer (score 0):

In my software, I'm making it possible to extract query objects from model and execute them from inside controllers:

```
$model->dsql()->where('age>',20)->do_delete();
```

So technically - yes, controller **can** execute queries, but it must rely on the model to build that query.